# Можно ли контролировать ввод данных

Tags: c

Можно ли в си как-то контролировать ввод данных? Например, чтобы в строку вводились только буквы? А на ввод чисел только из определенного диапазона, и если вводились какие-то другие символы не завершалась программа?

```
struct database {
    char name[30];
    char gender[5];
    int age;
    char educ[11];
};

struct database inputDB (void) {
    struct database db;
    int br;
    char * nm, * edc, * gend;

    puts ("Имя:");
    fgets (db.name, 30, stdin);
    nm = strchr (db.name, '\n');
    if ( nm ) *nm = '\0';
    else while (nm);

    puts("Пол:");
    do {
        fgets(db.gender, 5, stdin);
        gend = strchr (db.gender, '\n');
    } while ((strcmp(gend, "М")!=0) || (strcmp(gend, "Ж")!=0));
    if (gend) *gend = '\0';
    else while (getchar()!='\n');

    puts("Образование:");
    do {
        fgets(db.educ, 11, stdin);
        edc = strchr (db.educ, '\n');
    } while((strcmp(edc, "школа")!=0) || (strcmp(edc, "колледж")!=0) || (strcmp(edc, "колледж")!=0));
    if (edc) *edc='\0';
    else while(getchar()!='\n');

    return db;
}
```

Comment: Вы сами должны проводить подобный контроль и вызывать exit() для завершения программы

Comment: Например, через if или while? Но, если мне надо считывать, пока пользователь не введет корректные данные в файл?

Comment: Если это интерактивная программа ввода, то вы можете в цикле  вывести сообщение об ошибке формата, прочесть данные, например,  до `\n` (в случае ввода с терминала) и попросить пользователя повторить ввод этого поля. Вообще, все зависит от формата входных данных, который вы должны разработать

Comment: Пытался в do while, через обычный while с if реализовать, но не получалось как-то. Могу привести пример кода (добавить в вопрос), не знаю, правда зачем

Comment: Что пытаетесь вводить и что именно не получается? Только конкретный формат правильных данных опишите

Comment: Просто по идее мне нужно, чтобы пользователь корректно вводил свое имя (char строка), пол (char символ м или ж), год рождения (int) и какое у него образование (char  школа, колледж или вуз). Например, в имя считывает все символы, также и в пол, а когда пытаюсь ввести в год рождения буквы ввести, то вылетает

Comment: время уже позднее. Вы в тексте вопроса свои попытки напишите и завтра вечером (если раньше никто не удосужиться) я попробую вам помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Занудное это занятие, программа ввода полей с терминала.

Для простоты я ограничился ascii буквами в имени. Может быть завтра запрограммирую и русские (в utf-8).

Вот такая простыня получается:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


struct database {
    char name[30];
    char gender[5];
    int age;
    char educ[11];
};


int
trim_str_word (char *str)
{
  int n = 0;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; str[i] && isspace(str[i]); i++);
  for (; str[i] && !isspace(str[i]); i++)
    str[n++] = str[i];
  str[n] = 0;

  return n;
}

int
skip_nl ()
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c == '\n')
      break;

  return c;
}

int
input_str_field (const char *prompt, char *field, int f_size)
{
  int rc = EOF, n  = 0;

  printf("%s: ", prompt); fflush(stdout);
  while (fgets(field, f_size, stdin)) {
    if (field[strlen(field) - 1] != '\n')
      if ((rc = skip_nl()) == EOF)
        break;
    rc = 0;
    if ((n = trim_str_word(field)) != 0)
      break;
    puts("Empty input, try again");
    rc = EOF;
  }
  
  return rc == EOF ? rc : n;  
}

int
input_num_field (const char *prompt, int *pv)
{
  char str[32];
  char *ep;

  do {
    if (input_str_field(prompt, str, 31) == EOF)
      return EOF;
    long v = strtol(str, &ep, 10);
    *pv = v;
    if (*ep)
      puts("Invalid number, try again");
  } while (*ep);

  return 0;
}

int
inputDB (struct database *pdb)
{
  int nf = 0;
  
  do {
    if (input_str_field("name", pdb->name, sizeof(pdb->name) - 1) == EOF)
      return EOF;
    int goodname = 1;
    for (char *p = pdb->name; *p; p++)
      if (!isalpha(*p)) {
        puts("Invalid character, try again");
        goodname = 0;
        break;
      }
    if (goodname)
      break;
  } while (1);
  nf++;
  
  do {
    if (input_str_field("gender", pdb->gender, sizeof(pdb->gender) - 1) == EOF)
      return EOF;
    if (strcmp(pdb->gender, "M") == 0)
      break;
    if (strcmp(pdb->gender, "W") == 0)
      break;
    puts("invalid gender, try again");
  } while (1);
  nf++;

  do {
    if (input_num_field("birth year", &pdb->age) == EOF)
      return EOF;
    if (pdb->age < 1950 || pdb->age > 2010) {
      puts("invalid birth year, try again");
      continue;
    }
    pdb->age = 2022 - pdb->age; // конечно, тут надо вместо 2022 взять текущий год у системы
    break;
  } while (1);
  nf++;

  static const char *edu[] = {"scool", "college", "academy", 0};
  int found = 0;
  do {
    if (input_str_field("education", pdb->educ, sizeof(pdb->educ) - 1) == EOF)
      return EOF;
    for (int i = 0; edu[i]; i++)
      if (strcmp(pdb->educ, edu[i]) == 0) {
        found = 1;
        break;
      }
  } while (!found);
  nf++;

  return nf;
  
}
```

Я несколько изменил интерфейс функции `inputDB()` -- она получает адрес заполняемой структуры как параметр и возвращает число заполненных полей или EOF (по концу ввода данных пользователем).

---

Продолжение.

Если посмотреть на `inputDB()`, то можно заметить что действия по вводу каждого поля структуры весьма схожи между собой. Это вызывает желание написать подобную функцию, которая позволит осуществлять ввод сразу всех полей любой однотипной `struct database` структуры по некоторому описанию полей этой структуры, например, вот такому:

```
struct f_descr {
  char *prompt;
  void *field;
  int f_size;
  int f_type; // 1 string, else numeric
  int (*f_check) (struct f_descr *fdscr);
  void *f_check_args;
};
```

Тогда мы получаем функцию

```
int
input_struct (struct database *pdb, struct f_descr *d)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (; d[i].field; i++) {
    int rc = d[i].f_type ?
      input_str_field(d[i].prompt ? d[i].prompt : "", (char *)d[i].field, d[i].f_size) :
      input_num_field(d[i].prompt ? d[i].prompt : "", (int *)d[i].field);
    if (rc == EOF)
      return EOF;

    switch (rc = d[i].f_check(d + i)) {
    case EOF:
      return EOF;
    case -2: // not EOF, but stop input (at least stop input this struct)
      return -2;
    case 1: // Check OK, input next field
      break;
    case 0: // Check fail, no message
      puts("Unconsistent. Try again");
    default: // Check fail, message printed, repeat input
      i--;
      //      continue;
    }    
  }

  return i;
}
```

И после добавления нескольких вспомогательных функций

```
// аналогична `trim_str_word()`, но оставляет все "слова" в строке
int
trim_str (char *str)
{
  int n = 0;

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; str[i] && isspace(str[i]); i++);
  for (j = strlen(str) - 1; j > i && isspace(str[j]); j--);
  for (; i <= j; i++)
    str[n++] = str[i];
  str[n] = 0;

  return n;
}

static int rus_uc[] = {
  0x401, // Ё
  0x451, // ё
  0x410, // А
  0x42F, // Я
  0x430, // а
  0x44F  // я
};
               

int
rusletter_utf8_uc (char *s)
{
  if ((*s & 0xE0) != 0xC0 || (s[1] & 0xC0) != 0x80)
    return 0;
  int r = ((s[0] & 0x1f) << 6) + (s[1] & 0x3f);

  return ((r >= rus_uc[2] && r <= rus_uc[5]) || r == rus_uc[1] || r == rus_uc[0]) ?
    r : 0;
}

int
is_upper_rus (int uc)
{
  return uc == rus_uc[0] || (uc >= rus_uc[2] && uc <= rus_uc[3]);
}

int
check_name (struct f_descr *d)
{
  char *str = (char *)(d->field);

  int c;
  while (c = *str++)
    if (!isalpha(c) && !isspace(c))
      return 0;

  return 1;
}

int
check_rus_name (struct f_descr *d)
{
  char *str = (char *)(d->field);

  if (is_upper_rus(rusletter_utf8_uc(str))) {
    for (int i = 2; str[i]; i++) {
      if (isspace(str[i]))
        continue;
      if (!rusletter_utf8_uc(str + i))
        return 0;
      i++;  // because cyrillic symbols in utf-8 is 2 bytes length
    }

    return 1;
  }
  
  return check_name(d);
}


int
check_str_set (struct f_descr *d)
{
  char **a = (char **)(d->f_check_args);

  for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++) 
    if (strcmp(a[i], (char *)(d->field)) == 0)
      return 1; // OK, found

  printf("input `%s` not in any of: ", (char *)(d->field));
  for (int i = 0; a[i]; i++)
    printf("'%s' ", a[i]);
  printf(" Try again\n");
  
  return -3;  // wrong field, messagee printed, repeat the input
}

int
check_num_bounds (struct f_descr *d)
{
  int *a = (int *)(d->f_check_args);
  int v = *(int *)(d->field);
  
  return  v >= a[0] && v <= a[1];
}
```

Теперь мы можем писать вот такие компактные программы для ввода данных в достаточно произвольную структуру с желаемой проверкой вводимых полей

```
int
main()
{
  struct database dbs;
  static const char *valid_g[] = {"m", "f", "М", "Ж", 0};
  static const char *valid_edu[] = {"scool", "школа", "college", "academy", 0};
  static int birth_bnd[2] = {1950, 2010};
  
  struct f_descr dbs_dscr[] = {
    {"Name", dbs.name, sizeof(dbs.name) - 1, 1, check_rus_name, 0},
    {"Gender", dbs.gender, sizeof(dbs.gender) - 1, 1, check_str_set, valid_g},
    {"Birth year", &dbs.age, sizeof(int), 0, check_num_bounds, birth_bnd},
    {"Education", dbs.educ, sizeof(dbs.educ) - 1, 1, check_str_set, valid_edu},
    {0, 0}
  };
  
  int rc = 0;

  while ((rc = input_struct(&dbs, dbs_dscr)) != EOF)
    printf("rc = %d\ndbs: <%s> <%s> <%d> <%s>\n\n", rc,
       dbs.name, dbs.gender, dbs.age, dbs.educ);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

P.S.

Я сделал пример провеки вода имени для кодировки [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (см. также [Кириллица (блок Юникода)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_(%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0))) в предположении, что имя должно начинаться с большой буквы.

Надеюсь, аналогичную проверку для более простого случая однобайтной кодировки русского языка (например, CP-1251) вы сможете запрограммировать сами.

Answer (score -2):

Смотря какая платформа, если под Windows, вам поможет `_getch`, если Unix, то нужна библиотека ncurses

Comment: Попытать удачу можно через getc (кросс-платформный вариант)